# Unable to get the required object returned from the callback function

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, callback

I am trying to return the required object from the objects array where the array index is passed as a parameter to the callback function. E.g. if I want the object at array index 0 I call getInfo this way **getInfo(0, data)**. But the callback function **only returns the index back** and not the value. I tried to test the same with simple function called **myfunc** but that gives me what I want. What's the issue over here?

This is my code

```
const getInfo = (resource, callback) => {
let request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.addEventListener('readystatechange', () => {
        if(request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200 )
            {
                const data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
                console.log(data[resource]);
                myfunc(resource, data[resource]);
                callback(resource, data[resource]);
            }
    });

    request.open('GET','values.json');
    request.send();
};

const myfunc = (val,arr) =>{
    console.log(val,arr);
}

getInfo(0, data => {
    console.log(data);
    getInfo(2, data => {
        console.log(data);
        getInfo(1, data => {
                console.log(data);
        });
    });
});
```

**values.json**

```
[
    {"name" : "MM", "height" : "5 ft 2 inches"},
    {"name" : "DD", "height" : "5 ft 3 inches"},
    {"name" : "AA", "height" : "5 ft 5 inches"}
]
```

**Console Output**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you callback has only one parameter, but you are sending two arguments when calling the callback

```
getInfo(0, (index,data) => {
    console.log(data);
    getInfo(2, (index,data) => {
        console.log(data);
        getInfo(1, (index,data) => {
                console.log(data);
        });
    });
});
```